# UITableView Pagination

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

My app has custom `UITableView` cells. I want to show only one cell at a time - next cell should show partially. In ScrollView you can set `isPagingEnabled` to YES.

But how can i do above in `UITableView`?

Thanks

Comment: I have used uitableview setcontentoffset. That gives issues.Please give any ideas.

Comment: Consider using a basic scroll view for that if you have a small number of cells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so you can set `pagingEnabled`to `YES` on the table view itself.

Of course, this will only work if all cells and the table view itself are of the same height.

If you want to always have a cell start at the top of the table view after scrolling, you could use a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implement something like this.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
  UITableView *tv = (UITableView*)scrollView;
  NSIndexPath *indexPathOfTopRowAfterScrolling = [tv indexPathForRowAtPoint:
                                                       *targetContentOffset
                                                 ];
  CGRect rectForTopRowAfterScrolling = [tv rectForRowAtIndexPath:
                                             indexPathOfTopRowAfterScrolling
                                       ];
  targetContentOffset->y=rectForTopRowAfterScrolling.origin.y;
}
```

This lets you adjust at which content offset a scroll action will end.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 basic version, but it does not work that well. I needed to customize it for my own use to make it work.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if let tv = scrollView as? UITableView {
        let path = tv.indexPathForRow(at: targetContentOffset.pointee)
        if path != nil {
            self.scrollToRow(at: path!, at: .top, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Customized version

```
// If velocity is less than 0, then scrolling up
// If velocity is greater than 0, then scrolling down
if let tv = scrollView as? UITableView {
    let path = tv.indexPathForRow(at: targetContentOffset.pointee)
    if path != nil {
        // >= makes scrolling down easier but can have some weird behavior when scrolling up
        if velocity.y >= 0.0 {
            // Assumes 1 section
            // Jump to bottom one because user is scrolling down, and targetContentOffset is the very top of the screen
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: path!.row + 1, section: path!.section)
            if indexPath.row < self.numberOfRows(inSection: path!.section) {
                self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
            }
         } else {
             self.scrollToRow(at: path!, at: .top, animated: true)
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think I'd use a UITableView for this at all.

I think I'd use a UIScrollView with a tall stack of paged content. You could dynamically rebuild that content on scrolling activity, so you mimic the memory management of UITableView. UIScrollView will happily do vertical paging, depending on the shape of its contentView's frame.

In other words, I suspect it's easier to make a UIScrollView act like a table than to make a UITableView paginate like scroll view.

Comment: Not true if you got to have a sheeshload of data in the [scrollview/tableview] and you scroll fast through them - then the internal memory management of `UITableView` is the better option than native paging of `UIScrollView`, at least IMHO.